# Type of wire for high voltage applications

Tags: high-voltage, low-power, wire, static-electricity

What kind of wire is most suitable for HV low-current applications, where the allowed maximum is 25 kV and 5 W?

By type of wire I mean core and type of insulation.

As far as I can guess, even if the wire is thin it will not create much heat, because of the very low current and low resistance (especially if copper core is used), but silicone wires will leak static electricity (And that's a problem) if it's not thick and I would prefer thinner wire if possible.
On the other hand PTFE wires aren't usually rated at >15 kV
But perhaps coated wires is what I should be looking for?

Comment: Sounds dangerous

Comment: @Mikey It's not really. But it is harmful compared to low power electronics, evidently.

Comment: As far as I know, silicone wires is the way to go and will fit your 25kV specs as required. I don't have any alternative I can offer right away..

Comment: @Weaverworm Hmm.. I initially thought the same, but I gave it a second thought and discovered that while heat resistant, it actually leaks static electricity and if the ground wire is close to the HV output wire an ESD will occur.

Comment: [Have you considered automotive sparkplug wire?](https://pitstopusa.com/i-23901990-accel-superstock-spooled-wire-7mm-18-gauge-tinned-copper.html)  Well insulated, and deals with the relatively high temperatures close to the engine.

Comment: @JRE Sounds good, but I will have to find 4 meters of this special wire for a good price in the local store. I don't need that much of it.
It will be either very hard or simply impossible. I don't know what are the odds to find ANY EPDM thick wires per m under 5$
Also due to that I am tight on budget (Bulgarian stuff), I will not have second chance with something as expensive and hard to find. Something more conventional and practical will be good to use. That one is good to know.

Comment: If there's an automotive repair shop or parts store, you might just ask them.  They may have a roll of wire they use (repair shop) and could sell you a few meters.  The parts store might also have a roll they use to sell the wire by the meter for people who have to make their own custom cables.  Tell them what you are doing, and ask if they can sell you a few meters of sparkplug wire.  They might even be so amused by your project that they give you the wire, or make you a special price.

Comment: Since you added your desired price range and said you don't want something "hard to find" you have turned this into a shopping question. We don't do shopping questions here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Are you trying to prove that you you don't know the meaning of the comment section or just nagging on purpose?

Comment: @Edenia Questions like "What high-voltage cable can I buy if I only need a few meters and I only have $5 and it should be easy to find in Bulgaria" rarely help anyone else. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Are you kidding me? Those were just comments, my question is one and the same, stated at the top of this page and does not specifically require anything like that.

Comment: I understand that you have used comments to effectively change your question. @JRE gave you a great **engineering answer** to your original question but you dismissed it saying you needed "for a good price at a local store". (How is that **not** a shopping question with limited value?) You should include those requirements in your actual question rather than as comments.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson If I wanted to change my question I would have edited it, or appended text. Comments are not answers. How come you are so brutally misunderstanding this basic concept.. :/

Comment: How will you be using it? If it toutches anything but air you need to consider partial discharge (PD), especially if 25 kV DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question isn't getting much attention, I'm going to go ahead and expand my comments into an answer.

You need a type of wire rated for high voltage.  Temperature doesn't seem to be important, but flexibility is.

The correct thing to use would be silicone insulated wire rated to higher than your expected voltage.  Like [this stuff, for example.](http://www.daburn.com/2637-high-voltage-flexible-silicone-rubber-lead-wire.aspx)

That's just an example.  You can get it in different ratings and sizes from various manufacturers and sources.

An alternative for hobbyists would be [automotive sparkplug wire.](https://pitstopusa.com/i-23901990-accel-superstock-spooled-wire-7mm-18-gauge-tinned-copper.html)

It can be bought by the meter (or foot) at automotive parts stores, or (maybe if you ask nice) from automotive repair shops.

If you don't need long pieces, you can scrounge used sparkplug cables from the junkyard (or ask a repair shop.)

Most sparkplug wires are of the "resistor" type.  I seem to remember that you are working on some kind of electric "joy buzzer" gizmo, so resistor wire may be a good thing.

Resistor sparkplug wire has one down side, though.  You cannot solder it.

You will need to use the crimp on brass connectors.  You can solder to the brass parts after they are crimped on.

If you repurpose used spark plug wires, you will usually have a connector at each end.

If you buy new sparkplug wire, you can try to get wire core (like I linked to) rather than the resistor wire you will find in used sparkplug wires.  You can solder that rather than using the crimp on connectors.

If you try to buy new sparkplug wire, and can only get resistor sparkplug wire, then you will need some connectors.  Buy them where you buy the wire (or scrounge some old wires and pull the connectors out.)

---

Resistor sparkplug wires don't really contain what you would think of as wire.

It uses a string that is impregnated with carbon.  This gives it a high innate (built in) resistance without having a seperate resistor.

They use this stuff because it causes less radio interference when the sparkplugs fire.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a thinner wire, get a [*shielded HV cable*](https://www.hivolt.de/fileadmin/hivolt/img/130660_1.jpg): It has inner insulation (between the electrode and the shield) which is just thick enough to withstand the voltage, and the shield deals with electric field which otherwise requires a thick layer of insulation to prevent ESD.

Common HV insulation materials include silicone and different varieties of polyethylene. Shielded HV cables with silicone insulation don't have ESD problems AFAIK.